# How to mention more than one person's occupation in the sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

> Doris (Bookkeeper) & her husband Ed Crane (who is a barber), Big Dave (Doris's  Boss) & his wife Ann having dinner at Ed Crane's house.

This four people having dinner at Ed Crane's house, But I am facing difficulty because of their occupations, so how to rephrase it without brackets .

Comment: @P.E.Dant why you separated **having** and **dinner** in your sentence? I think they both should be side-by-side like this **having dinner**. So please explain it.

Comment: The phrasal verb _"having sb over for dinner"_ is commonly separated in English just as in that sentence, e.g. _"Lurleen and Billy Bob McCoy are having the Hatfields over for dinner."_ This is simple, idiomatic English. It has nothing to do with the phrase "having dinner."

Comment: Bookkeeper Doris and her barber husband, Ed Crane, host a dinner for Doris's boss, Big Dave, and his wife Ann.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doris Crane, a bookkeeper, and husband, Ed, a barber, are hosting dinner for Doris's boss, Big Dave, and wife, Ann.

Commas are somewhat a matter of taste so some might prefer -

Doris Crane, a bookkeeper, and husband Ed, a barber, are hosting dinner for Doris's boss, Big Dave, and wife Ann.